# Creating a scrollable (vertical and horizontal) grid container within a div?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am trying to import some data from a spreadsheet and I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally as well as vertically to access the needed grid area and cells. Is there a way to create a scrollable grid within a div use CSS grid/flexbox, displaying the x and y axis and their respective spots, with the grid data in the cells, being scrollable?

Comment: Because this is a coding platform, you need to give us some starting point. A HTML Code or perhaps a link, or an image? Please read [**how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Demian is right. There is no way for us to help you without the related HTML&CSS code. Show us what you've tried, or where you are at in the process, and we can help you find the error (or solve the problem).